# How to sort a tuple dictionary to list, How to use CompareTo properly

Tags: vb.net, sorting, tuples, key-value, compareto

I currently use this method below and it works fine, I just want to know how do you chain CompareTo's on Tuples to do Item2 first sorting then Item1 second sorting after Item2 sort is complete like GroupBy/ThenBy how do you chain them together?

```
   Dim newListOfValues As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), Byte)) = ListOfValues.ToList()

    newListOfValues.Sort(
        Function(pair1 As KeyValuePair(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), Byte), pair2 As KeyValuePair(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), Byte))
            Return pair1.Key.Item2.CompareTo(pair2.Key.Item2) AndAlso pair1.Key.Item1.CompareTo(pair2.Key.Item1)
        End Function)
```

at the moment this code is no different then

```
        newListOfValues.Sort(
            Function(pair1 As KeyValuePair(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), Byte), pair2 As KeyValuePair(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), Byte))
                Return pair1.Key.Item2.CompareTo(pair2.Key.Item2)
            End Function)
```

The thing is it works perfectly anyways so I guess no need for the extra compare

Comment: *is it works perfectly anyways* - while Item1 is distinct, that is...

Comment: I think by the time you've created a `KeyValuePair(Of Tuple(Of Int, Int), Of Byte)` you've probably reached that point where it would be sensible to put your data in a class. At the very least you could perhaps ditch the KVP and just use a 3 element tuple. You can give members names too: `Dim x = (X:=1,Y:=2,Color:=255)` and bonus, they already implement CompareTo on all elements, left to right so for `Dim y =  (X:=1,Y:=1,Color:=255)` will sort *before* `x` and `(X:=2,Y:=2,Color:=255)` will sort after `x`